# Mysql Logs In without Password, Denied with Password

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords

I've just built a new mysql instance and am not able to connect with 2 users I created. After the creation I connected (no password because it is the first login) with:

> mysql -uroot

and once connected I ran

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('Password1');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'generic_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password2';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password3';
```

to secure my root user and attempt to create a user for my web application and for administrating it. Connecting with `root` and `Password1` (not the actual password) worked fine BUT the `generic_user` fails to connect using `Password2` **if** I use the password. If I go with no password and the `generic_user` I am granted access.

e.g.

> mysql -ugeneric_user
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

verse secure attempt:

> mysql -ugeneric_user -p
>   Enter password: 
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'generic_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm copying and pasting the password from my `GRANT` command so I know it is correct.

I saw somethings about the `my.cnf` containing credentials but my `my.cnf` doesn't have that either:

```
# Percona Server template configuration

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
default-time-zone="America/New_York"
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

... UPDATE ...

After more fiddling I think I'm connecting as a different user.

I ran:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mysql.proxies_priv;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

after I found that `user()` and `current_user()` were returning me as `root`.

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

now I'm getting:

```
+------------------------+----------------+
| USER()                 | CURRENT_USER() |
+------------------------+----------------+
| generic_user@localhost | @localhost     |
+------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You'd put credentials in either .my.cnf in your home directory (note the first dot) or in .mylogin.cnf. The former would store the password in cleartext, the latter is generated with mysql_config_editor and allows you to store an encrypted password.

Comment: I don't want the credentials in a file, I want them in the mysql.user table. I initially thought one of the other threads I found was the cause but have ruled that out.

Comment: You seemed to be looking for credentials in my.cnf, I was just pointing out that you probably meant .my.cnf instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there was a generic user account set up. I followed this answer, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897, with a few additional pieces.

After verifying I had a generic account with

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='' AND host='localhost';
```

I deleted but still could access because I didn't flush the privileges so the full commands should be:

```
delete FROM  mysql.user WHERE user='' AND host='localhost';
```

then in the shell

```
mysqladmin flush-privileges -uroot -p
mysqladmin reload -uroot -p
service mysql restart
```

I don't think the restart is necessary.